# Appium flutter : Check Dart Observatory URI no URI found in the device log

Tags: flutter, appium, appium-ios

**What should I do when I try to connect Appium to an application developed by Flutter on iOS?**

I problem issue related to this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp4PQ.png)

how to solve this problem.
ิี

execute test app ios flutter pass.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an instrumented build that exposes the websocket url, i.e "ObservatoryWsUri" in this case. Without exposing this ws url you may not be able to communicate with dart VM layer, in other words flutter automation is not possible.

In order to expose this URL may can try to talk to your flutter developer to include below line of code in entrypoint(main.dart) file and provide instrumented build to you.

```
enableFlutterDriverExtension(
  commands: [],
  finders: []
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can automate the release build by adding this code in main.dart

`enableFlutterDriverExtension( commands: [], finders: [] );`

Answer (score 0):

Add your app need dependency and some setup

1. Add flutter_driver to you .yaml flutter

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
```

2. Add `enableFlutterDriverExtension()` to main() function

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
...
void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

And when build app file you need to build with `--debug`

I hope this solution work for you.

Answer (score 0):

for iOS You have to use profile Mode
For iOS 14 and higher, please build the app in profile mode only.